# Can I query the MWL (Modality Worklist) by accession number in FO-DICOM?

Tags: fo-dicom

How can I query the MWL using FO-DICOM by accession number? When I call the CreateWorklistQuery method accession number is not one of the parameters i can use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very easy to do. A WorklistQuery is a Dataset, that contains some DicomTags that are queried. Some of those DicomTags may contain values, then the Worklist Server has to use those values as filters.

So basically a WorklistQuery is a normal DicomDataset, that you can extend and manipulate. The helper-methods `DicomCFindRequest.CreateWorklistQuery()` is a helper-method that creates common used datasets. But you can then update/change this DicomDataset before sending to the server.

```
var accessionNumberToFilter = "ABCD1234";
[....]
var findRequest = DicomCFindRequest.CreateWorklistQuery(); // create a basic query Dataset without any filters
findRequest.Dataset.AddOrUpdate(DicomTag.AccessionNumber, accessionNumberToFilter);
[....]
await client.AddRequestAsync(findRequest);
await client.SendAsync();
```